# Using multiple CheckStylePublisher in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline definition looks like this (excerpt):

```
eslint: {stage('ES Lint') {
            sh "bin/eslint ..."
            step([$class: 'CheckStylePublisher', pattern:...])
        }},

stylelint: {stage('Style Lint') {
            sh "..."
            sh "..."
            step([$class: 'CheckStylePublisher', pattern: '...'])
            step([$class: 'CheckStylePublisher', pattern: '...'])
        }},

        ...
```

I have many steps that call the CheckStylePublisher. Unfortunately when displaying the output in the Jenkins UI, I see several CheckStylePublisher graphs, but they have no reference to the respective step.

[image: CheckStyle graphs without information]

Is there any way to name the CheckStylePublisher instances and link them to the stage name somehow? Thanks

Comment: You may want to file this as an RFE with the Checkstyle Plugin project, see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin